# How to save text view color in onSaveInstanceState() after rotaing phone to landscape position?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

After i click the button it change text color to red when my phone is in portrait position. After configuration change (Rotation) to landscape position i was able to retaind textview data that contain number but the color changed back to textview default color. So i want it to stay red even after configuration change.

```
private var healthLevel: Int = 10 //Set the initial health level to 10
    private lateinit var healthLevelTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var sneezeButton: Button
    private lateinit var takeMedicationButton: Button
    private lateinit var blowNoseButton: Button

private fun changeTextColor() {
        // When the health falls to level 7 and below, change the text colour to light blue.
        if (healthLevel in 6..7) {
            healthLevelTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ADD8E6"))
            Log.i(TAG, "Called changeTextColor() to light blue when level 7 and below")
        }
        //The text should be a neutral colour above 7 (Text default color)
        else if (healthLevel  in 8..10) {
            healthLevelTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
            Log.i(TAG, "Called changeTextColor() to neutral color when above 7")
        }
        // If it falls to level 5 and below, change the text colour of the score to red
        else if (healthLevel in 5 downTo 0) {
            healthLevelTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
            Log.i(TAG, "Called changeTextColor() to red when level 5 & below")
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putInt("Answer", healthLevel)
        Log.i(TAG, "Called SaveInstanceState()")
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        healthLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("Answer")
        val answer = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.health_level)
        answer.text = healthLevel.toString()
        answer.textColors
        Log.i(TAG, "Called restoredInstanceState")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manifest add this to your activity tag:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

have a good day!

Comment: I already found a better way by myself. Thanks for the help thou

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Kotlin I suggest using viewModels to hold business logic, it survives configuration and lifecycle changes